# android emulator allocate memory error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried start emulator as user and as root:

```
ps / # /home/pscat/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd avd4.0
Could not configure '/dev/rtc' to have a 1024 Hz timer. This is not a fatal
error, but for better emulation accuracy either use a 2.6 host Linux kernel or
type 'echo 1024 > /proc/sys/dev/rtc/max-user-freq' as root.
Failed to allocate 536870912 B: Cannot allocate memory
```

What should I do with this?

Comment: Solved. Reboot help to me, thanks :)